# Not able to change state of a local variable in other function using pointer to that variable

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, linked-list

I wrote a method to merge two sorted linked lists(LLs are in ascending order) into one. By using double pointer I passed address of my head pointer from calling function(main) to the called function(mergeSortedLL).

```
//definition of listNode
    struct ListNode{
    int data;
    struct ListNode *next;
    };


void mergeSortedLL(struct ListNode **headA,struct ListNode *prevA,struct ListNode **headB,struct ListNode *prevB)
{
    struct ListNode *currA=*headA,*currB=*headB;
    static struct ListNode *finalHead=NULL;


//  Base Condition
if(!currA || !currB)
{

    *headA=finalHead;                     // this should change head in main function
      printList(*headA);                  // LINE-1  this function prints data of linked list sequentially. 
    return;
}

    struct ListNode *nextA=currA->next, *nextB=currB->next;

    if(currA->data>currB->data)
    {
        if(!finalHead)
            finalHead=currB;           // finalhead points to head of that LL which starts with smaller value node

        currB->next=currA;
        if(prevB)
            prevB->next=currB;
        mergeSortedLL(&currA,currB,&nextB,currB);
    }

    else
    {
        if(!finalHead)
            finalHead=currA;           //finalhead points to head of that LL which starts with smaller value node

        currA->next=currB;
        if(prevA)
            prevA->next=currA;
        mergeSortedLL(&nextA,currA,&currB,currA);
    }
}
```

In the main function i have created two LL
head==>    -1->3->5->6->8->9                                   first node is -1 
head2==>    0->1->4->5->7->8->9
and after calling from main

```
mergeSortedLL(&head,NULL,&head2,NULL);
printList(head);                             //Line-2
```

Thing that i am not able to predict is Line-1 of mergeSortedLL function always prints desired sorted LL while printList method at Line-2 in main sometimes requires `head` to be passed and sometimes `head2` to be passed for getting desired output (0113455678899).
for instance if first LL is changed to `head==> 1->3->5->6->8->9`, (first node is positive 1) Line-2 requires head2 to be passed instead of head to get the desired o/p.
How it is happening as in mergeSoretedLL method by means of double pointerd headA i am changing the head (of main function) to point to finalHead.
I think somehow values of headA and headB are getting swapped but i am not able to see it here.
Somebody please explain it.

Comment: Pretty hard to figure out without a debugger IMO

Comment: Do you use recursion for its own purpose here (i.e. for learning)? Otherwise I would recommend to use an iteration here. It's easier to implement and understand (i.e. less error prone), a bit more performant and saves (stack) memory space.

Comment: yes i know other solutions as well which don't look complex.  But my concern is when Line-1 is giving right result  and headA is holding reference of head (as passed from main) when why Line-2 in main is not giving the same result.

Comment: make sure that in the first recursion level, you assign the headA to the intended node's address. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign :

```
*headA=finalHead;
```

in the if and else statement as well.i.e, as below:

```
if(!finalHead) {  // in if case
    finalHead=currB; 
    *headA = finalHead;
}

...
...

if(!finalHead) {  // in else case
    finalHead=currA; 
    *headA = finalHead;
}
```

This is because when you call from main, currA and CurrB are not NULL because *headA and *headB are not NULL. So, your code enters if or else statement based on `currA->data > currB->data` is true or not. Here, you assign assign the finalHead to currA or currB, but, this is not reflected in *headA (head in main). So, obviously when you print from main, you won't get the result.

So, make sure that in the first recursion level, you assign the headA to the intended node's address.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. now its working fine but i still didnt get how this modification made the code to work. Why assigning *headA=finalHead in base condition is not working here? Can you please clarify it

Comment: oh i got.. headA is getting changed every time in each recursion thats why its not working.. Is it right?

Comment: no. in the base case, you were not assigning value to *headA. This is because, currA and currB are not NULL. so it never assigned *headA for first level of recursion. Also, please accept the answer, if it solves the issue.

Comment: in the first level of recursion, that is when called from main, it does not enter base condition. So, *headA is not changed. You were rightly changing the value of finalHead in the if and else, but this was not assigned to *headA for 1 Recursion. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: but   if(!finalHead)    is executed only 1 time and and at last as the base condition runs *headA is assigned with the previously chosen finalHead.

Comment: but, that is in subsequent recursion level. i.e, the address of currA or nextA is changed to finalHead, not the &head. Because, you are calling mergeSortedLL(&currA,currB,&nextB,currB); or mergeSortedLL(&nextA,currA,&currB,currA);, so, in 2nd level of recursion, headA points to currA or nextA and not head (head from main).

Comment: That is the reason it prints inside base condition of subsequent recursion but not in main.

Comment: yes i got your point.. in first level of recursion *headA is not getting assigned by finalHead. but in the last level of recursion it will be assigned in the base condition as recursion terminates here. So at last(in the last level of recursion) i am  assigning *head=finalHead. Hope i am clear in putting my point.

Comment: yes, but in last level of recursion, headA does not point to address of head, it is address of currA or nextA of the previous level of recursion. Hope you got this. That is the reason, head (from main) is not changed.

Comment: Thats what i was saying.Now its clear.. Thank you.. :)